# Oracle inactive connection

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle10g

There are a lot of inactive connection in my oracle server. I retrieve SQL text from those inactive. The SQL test is

```
SELECT PARAMETER, VALUE FROM SYS.NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET')
```

but I never use the SQL statement in my system, and do not know why the statement run automatically without closing automatically.

Comment: what processes are creating these connections?

Comment: Are you using connection pooling? [others with similar issue](http://www.mindscapehq.com/forums/thread/2515)

Comment: See this thread from the Oracle forums https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=251419

Answer (score 3):

Is there a problem?  In most systems, most sessions are inactive the vast majority of the time.  An inactive session merely indicates that at the instant you queried the data dictionary, a SQL statement was not being executed.  Whether you are talking about a client-server application or a three tier application where the middle tier has a pool of connections, most of the time, you're waiting either for the application to process some data or for the user to make a decision.  During that time, the database session will be inactive.

As for the query you're seeing, I would strongly wager that this is simply a query that whatever database driver/ framework you are using (your ODBC driver, OLE DB driver, ODP.Net provider, etc.) executes either when a connection is opened or when it is returned to a middle tier connection pool.