# Pooling Not Reusing INACTIVE Sessions

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, session-state

This is a general question about flow - 
Lately we started getting warnings by .Net of *Connection timeout* or *Connection must be open for this operation*.
We are working with Oracle DB and we set a job running every 5 seconds, counting how many connections are there (both ACTIVE and INACTIVE) by the w3wp (we are querying gv$session).
The max pool size for each WS (we have 2) is 300, meaning 600 connections in total.
We noticed that indeed we are reaching the 600 sessions before the crash, however, there are many INACTIVE sessions out of those 600 sessions.
I would except that those sessions would be reused, since they are INACTIVE at the moment.
In addition, the prev_sql_id being running by most of these INACTIVE sessions is: *SELECT PARAMETER, VALUE FROM SYS.NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET')*.

Is it a normal behavior?

Further more, after recycling, the connection count is of course small (around 30), but 1 minute later it jumps into 200. Again, the majority are INACTIVE sessions.
What is the best way to understand what are these sessions and troubleshoot it?

Thanks!

Comment: We have the same issue, did you ever solve this?

Comment: Its an Oracle bug! We opend SR and still working with them.

Comment: We have the same issues, no luck resolving yet.
Similar cases
http://www.mindscapehq.com/forums/thread/2515
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514852/oracle-inactive-connection